# Chat transcript @-highlighting malfunction

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, notifications, chat-transcript

So I was sifting through the Tavern on the Meta chat history for `poke stick` (it was a link somewhere; can't remember where) when on [page 8 (Jan 26 '11 5:06 PM)](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=poke%20stick&Room=89&page=8&pagesize=50&sort=relevance) something interesting happened:

[image: It's highlighting a prefix of my username!]

I realise [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67328/getting-transcript-reminders-for-people-that-arent-me) covers roughly the same ground, but there's a difference: here, the offending message was sent **ten months before I registered anywhere on SE** (so obviously I wasn't pinged), *(edit)* and I've never actually entered Tavern on the Meta, yet I'm still having prefixes of my username highlighted in the transcript.

The key point here is I didn't exist, so the message couldn't have been for me, so it shouldn't be highlighted as if it could have been for me.

Reasons? Bugfix timelines? [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)s? [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinging and highlighting do not have to coincide. When you look at a transcript (or at the live chat), any instance of an "@" followed by (a mentionable part of) your displayname is highlighted, whether or not this message actually pinged you or not.